# Variable separation between items in a list environment

Tags: spacing, lists

Is it possible to define a list environment where each item has a user-specified amount of space below it? I'm looking for something to the effect of

```
\begin{myitemize}
    \item[1in] One
    \item[.5in] Two
    \item[2in] Three
\end{myitemize}

Some text...
```

In the compiled document, there should be 1 in of space between "One" and "Two", .5 in between "Two" and "Three", and 2 in between "Three" and "Some text".

My best attempt so far resembles

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\itemspace}
\let\olditem\item

\newenvironment{myitemize}{
    \setlength{\itemspace}{0in}
    \begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][0in]{
        \vspace{\itemspace}
        \olditem
        \setlength{\itemspace}{##1}}
}{
    \vspace{\itemspace}
    \end{itemize}
}


\begin{document}
 Some text
\begin{myitemize}
\item[0in] Foo\underline{\hspace{4.3in}}
\item Bar
\item Baz
\end{myitemize}
Some other text
\end{document}
```

The problem shows up in the first item. With 0in specified, the spacing between Foo and Bar should be the same as the spacing between Bar and Baz. However, I get something like this:

[image]

The problem seems to be that the length of the first line is *exactly* the maximum line width. Adding the vspace afterwards seems to be also add a small amount of horizontal space, forcing TeX to start a new line before the next item. Shortening the hspace to only 4.2in causes the extra line to disappear.

Edit: For an even simpler example of my problem,

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo\underline{\hspace{4.3in}}\vspace{0in}
\item Bar
\item Baz
\end{itemize}
```

has no extra line, but

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo\underline{\hspace{4.3in}}
\vspace{0in}
\item Bar
\item Baz
\end{itemize}
```

does. Why does this happen?

Comment: isn't this `\vspace{1in}\item One \vspace{xx} \item two` ?

Comment: Not quite... that places the 1in of vspace _above_ \item one, whereas I'd like it below. I did try something similar; however, it leads to some unwanted behavior in certain cases. I've added more detail to my original question to clear things up.

Comment: Yes sure but put the 1in before the second item in that case. Your `horizontal space is most likely due to you not using `%` at ends of lines so adding white space (also you should have a \par or blank line before vspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the bad spacing in your example is due to the spurious space you've added from the end of line characters, This just adds `\par` before `\vspace` so it is used in vertical mode, and `%` to avoid adding white space

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\itemspace}
\let\olditem\item

\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
    \setlength{\itemspace}{0in}%
    \begin{itemize}%
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][0in]{%
        \par\vspace{\itemspace}%
        \olditem
        \setlength{\itemspace}{##1}}%
}{%
    \par\vspace{\itemspace}%
    \end{itemize}%
}


\begin{document}
 Some text
\begin{myitemize}
\item[0in] Foo\underline{\hspace{4.3in}}
\item Bar
\item Baz
\end{myitemize}
Some other text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm still a little confused about how TeX interprets ends of lines, though - can you recommend any resources for explaining this?

Comment: @TheMac it treats them exactly the same as a space.  but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines